# Remove linebreaks w/o \r\n

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently working on a website and doing some JS stuff. I'm fairly new to this topic, so please excuse if my question is stupid:)

I have a JSON string with some line breaks, however I cannot parse it into an JSON object (because of the line breaks) - so I need to remove them and already tried it using

```
stringJSON.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/, '');
```

However, this doesn't work, when I do an alert on the string the line breaks are still included.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Wiwi :)

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "key0": "value 0",
        "key1": "value 1",
        "key2": "value 2"
    },
    {
        "key0": "value 0",
        "key1": "value 1",
        "key2": "value 2"
    }
]
```

Comment: *"I cannot parse it into an JSON object"* If you have valid JSON then it can be parsed. Instead of "fixing" the JSON in retrospect, you should generate valid JSON to begin with.

Comment: That#s my JSON, is it wrong? o.O[
 {
  "key0": "value 0",
  "key1": "value 1",
  "key2": "value 2"
 },
 {
  "key0": "value 0",
  "key1": "value 1",
  "key2": "value 2"
 }
]

Comment: JSON can absolutely contain newlines.  How are you trying to parse it, and what error does it give you?

Comment: *"That#s my JSON, is it wrong?"* Well, *you* said you cannot parse it. If you cannot parse it, something must be wrong. How do you currently generate the JSON? Can you include a properly formatted example in your question?

Comment: I do var finalJSON = JSON.parse(stringJSON);

Comment: That is *parsing* the JSON. `finalJSON` contains an object, not JSON. How is the value of `stringJSON` generated? *edit:* What you posted is valid JSON. `JSON.parse` won't have any problems to parse that: https://jsfiddle.net/0frsex3h/ . Please post an example that actually represents the issue. See [mcve] for help.

Comment: stringJSON is generated in a loop. The actual data are string only, not even numbers or anything, just text and line breaks... I'm not allowed to post the actual data...

Comment: *"stringJSON is generated in a loop."* That's probably the mistake. Never build JSON manually. And if you are generating `stringJSON` in JavaScript then this is the wrong approach anyway. You should directly generate an array of objects, not JSON. JSON is a data serialization format to transfer data between server and clients.

Comment: Oh I see. So I'll take a look at that, thank you very much!

Comment: You should use a library to generate the JSON in the server-side. It depends on the language you're using, normally the base libraries provide methods to encode JSON. json_encode in PHP, JSON.stringify in Javascript/Node.js. Search in google an utility method in your server-side language, that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the result of the replace to the stringJSON variable if what you really mean to do is to update the stringJSON variable.

```
stringJSON = stringJSON.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/g, '');
```

Replace doesn't change the original string because strings are immutable in Javascript.

Note: The global flag on the regex (g) allows it to match more than once. Without that flag, only the first line break would be replaced.

Comment: I see, but it doesn't work. The alert still shows the line breaks and the console tells me an error at the position of a lb...

Comment: This is the wrong approach to solving the problem anyway. It's more reliable  to generate valid JSON to begin with.

Comment: I didn't realize first that end lines shouldn't have affected to the result, they are valid JSON. Sorry for the quick response, I also accepted Dominic edit that was more accurate.